# Clicking li to display array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a JS array of objects (cards) and an html list of the names of the cards and I want to make it so the object values are displayed in a div container when I click on the name of the card. So if I click "Ace of Wands", I want to reference that object in the array.

My thinking so far is to search the array for an object whose "image" == the id of the list item.

For example, he id for the list item Ace of Wands is "aow" and the image property of that object in the array is "aow", but I can't figure out how to connect these.

Can someone help me put these things together? I'm really new to this. Thanks!

HTML:

```
                    <ul>
                        <li id="aow">Ace</li>
                        <li id="2ow">Two</li>
                        <li id="3ow">Three</li>
                    </ul>

    <div id="card"></div>
    <div id="card-info"></div>
```

Array:

```
var cards = [ 
{
    name:"Ace of Wands",
    description:"new passion",
    meaning:"new passion", 
    image:"aow",
  },
 {
    name:"Two of Wands",
    description:"expansion",
    meaning:"planning", 
    image:"2ow",
  },
 {
    name:"Three of Wands",
    description:"travel",
    meaning:"expansion", 
    image:"3ow",
  },
```

I think in jQuery it should look something like this...????

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li", this).click(function(){
    var i = index.cards.image??????
    $("#card-info").html('<p><h2>' + cards[i].name + '</h2></p>' + '<p>' 
    + cards[i].meaning + '</p>' + '<p>' + cards[i].description + '</p>'); 
    $("#card").html('<img src=" images/cards/' + cards[i].image + '.jpg">');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code. I changed nothing

```
<ul>
   <li id="aow">Ace of Wands</li>
   <li id="2ow">Two of Wands</li>
   <li id="3ow">Three of Wands</li>
 </ul>
 <div id="card"></div>
 <div id="card-info"></div>
```

This is your cards array of objects. You forgot the end bracket.

```
var cards = [{
    name: "Ace of Wands",
    description: "new passion",
    meaning: "new passion",
    image: "aow",
  },
  {
    name: "Two of Wands",
    description: "expansion",
    meaning: "planning",
    image: "2ow",
  },
  {
    name: "Three of Wands",
    description: "travel",
    meaning: "expansion",
    image: "3ow",
  }
];
console.log('array', cards);
```

Just get the id of the clicked li element. Then make a each loop through your array of Objects. The id must be the same as the image value in your object. I build a markupCard for the card div tag and a markupInfo for the cardinfo div tag. Just append the markup to the certain div tag. That's it.

```
var id;
var markupCard;
var markupInfo;
$("li").click(function(e) {
  console.log('id', $(this).attr('id'));
  id = $(this).attr('id');
  $.each(cards, function(key, value) {
    if (id == value.image) {
      $("#card").empty();
      $("#card-info").empty();
      markupInfo = '<p><h2>' + value.name + '</h2></p>';
      markupInfo += '<p>' + value.meaning + '</p>';
      markupInfo += '<p>' + value.description + '</p>';
      console.log('markupInfo', markupInfo);
      $("#card-info").append(markupInfo);
      markupCard = '<img src="images/cards/' + value.image + '.jpg">';
      console.log('markupCard', markupCard);
      $("#card").append(markupCard);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what code you've changed and why. See [answer], where it mentions "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."